# Create a search form that will get the input from the user and will show the popup of video

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I am working on a search form that will get the input from the user and will show the popup of video, the user input and video name will be same.
the videos will be in the directory i.e. 1.mp4, 2.mp4 etc

Now my coding is working for only showing the link, I want that if the video name and search text field input is same the video pop-up should be open.
I don't know how can I merge the video modal / pop-up that will auto play. Please help.
Thanks a lot in advance.

**this is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Find Your Seat</title>

</head>
<body>


    <h2>find your seat</h2>
    <form method="post">

        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="type your seat id">

        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Enter</button>

    </form>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $filename =  $_POST['search'];

    $dir = "videos";

    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

                if($file == $_POST['search'])

                    {

                        echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
                    } 

            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }

}


?>


</body>
</html>
```

**the output of form is**

[image]

**required output**
for example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your **required output** image, this is a Youtube video embed which does not need the files to be present in your server directory and can be done with just an `iframe` having the Youtube video link inserted. An example is:

```html
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/youtube_video_id" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, if you want the video loaded from your directory. Then you can use the `video` element. Example is:

```html
...
echo('<video src="src_to_your_video.mp4" height="500" width="500" controls />');
...
```

### Modal Dialog

If you want these results in a modal dialog, then you could make a request with AJAX, on the same page and show the result as a popup. Something like this should work using a jQuery.

#### Your JavaScript

```js
//Provided you have the jQuery libary loaded to your script

$("#seat_form").submit(
function(e)
{
//Prevent the form from reloading or submitting
e.preventDefault();
//Get the user input value
var search = $("#search");

$.ajax(
{
   method:"POST",
   url: "get_video.php",
   data: {search:search.val()},
   success:function(response)
   {
      //Set the inner HTML of the modal to the response
      $("#modal_body").html(response)
      
      // Fade in the modal to show popoup
      $("#modal").fadeIn();
   },
   error: function()
   {
     //Handle your errors here in case the requests is not successful
   }
})

});

//Make the modal close when the close is clicked

$("#close").click(function()
{
    $("#modal").fadeOut()
})
```

#### Your CSS

```css
#modal
{
   display:none;
   position:fixed;
   background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
   width:100;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
}

#close
{
   color:white;
   position:absolute:
   font-size:1em;
   right:10px;
   top:10px;
   cursor:pointer;
}

#modal_body
{
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

#### Your HTML

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Find Your Seat</title>

</head>
<body>


    <h2>find your seat</h2>
    <form method="post" id="seat_form">

        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="type your seat id">

        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Enter</button>

    </form>
<!-- Define your modal HTML -->
<div id="modal">
<span id="close">&times;</span>
<div id="modal_body"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Your PHP File (get_video.php)

```js
<?php
//First confirm if the request is coming from a POST, and then check if it is AJAX
if(isset($_POST) && strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) == "xmlhttprequest")
{
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $filename =  $_POST['search'];

    $dir = "videos";

    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

                if($file == $_POST['search'])

                    {

                        echo("<video src='$dir.$file' height='500' width='500' controls />");
                    } 

            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
else
{
   echo 'Error: please input a search string';
}

}


?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Erisan Olasheni you have solved my problem, it works perfectly. only one small thing is there, which is the extension of the file, i have to search the full file name with its extension, i want to search the file without extension i.e. myvideo instead of myvideo.mp4

Comment: Ok, you may want to do that if you are sure that the file extension is static (.mp4), then your PHP code could look like this: `if($file == $_POST['search'].".mp4")`

Comment: A string to lower case comparison might also be better if you are sure there won't the letter case issues with your file names, and you also want to reduce the pain of getting the right files by your users `if(strtolower($file) == strtolower($_POST['search'].".mp4"))`

Comment: yaaah !!.. hurryyyyyyyyyyyy... thanks a lot bro... u r the best.. :)